# does the game make it easier to get gold camo once you already got it

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Is it easier to get gold camo once you prestige and have already gotten the camo

Answer (score 1):

You do not lose any of your unlocked camos when you prestige. If you do prestige, you will still have all of your unlocked camos for each weapon